# How to get as e.target the exact element at which onClick is specified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events, children

I have a React Component and give it `onClick` event handler:

```
function Item(props) {
  return <li onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</li>
}
```

Then I use the Component like this:

```
<Item onClick={ function(e) {console.log(e.target)} }>
  <span>This element is returned as e.target if clicked on it!</span>
</Item>
```

When I click on the text, the *span* element is logged as target and when it is clicked outside given span, *li* element is logged as target.

The problem is:
If there is a lot of child elements inside *li* element, and id or name are have to be gotten, it becomes a "hacky" task...

The question is:
Is it possible to get inside a handler function as e.target the exact element at which `onClick` is specified (not it's children; in this case *li*)?

PS. No jQuery for solution if possible.

Comment: @dschu I wanted to get <li> (the element at which onClick() is specified) when I click on <span> (the child of <li>).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`event.target` will always give you the element, which dispatched the event. In order to get the element who's listener is currently processed, you have to use `event.currentTarget`.

This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

Here is a simple example to illustrated your issue:

```js
const Inner = () => <div className="inner">Inner</div>

const Outer = () => {
  const clickHandler = e => {
    console.log('target:', e.target.getAttribute('class'));
    console.log('currentTarget:', e.currentTarget.getAttribute('class'));
  };

  return (<div className="outer" onClick={clickHandler}><Inner /></div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<Outer/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.outer {
  background: rosybrown;
  padding: 40px;
}

.inner {
  background: cornsilk;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;
function Item(props) {
  return <li onClick={props.onClick}
             {props.children}
         </li>
}

render( 
  <Item onClick = {
    function(e) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget)
    }
  }>
    <span> This element is returned as e.target if clicked on it! </span>
  </Item>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```